# Selenium WebDriver not recognizing an element, tried many options?NoSuch element exception coming?

Tags: java, css-selectors, webdriver

Ticket Operator 2 - 70002 - 15000038

```html
<option class="LstOptSel_sun4" dojoattachpoint="optionNode" value="41" label="Ticket Operator 2 - 70002 - 15000038">Ticket Operator 2 - 70002 - 15000038</option>
```

Comment: The record is dynamically created .

Comment: Can you please share HTML code of that section and webdriver code you have written?

Answer (score 0):

Few things you want to do then.

1. Make sure the element is not inside iframe
2. If that's the only element I would use css with regex. such as `[ label^='Ticket Operator 2']`
3. #2 can be accomplished using text based xpath as well. `//option[contains(text(),'Ticket Operator 2')]`

Answer (score 0):

If the class "LstOptSel_sun4" is unique then you can use two different locators for finding the element and also you are saying that this is coming dynamic so make sure to wait implicitly for that particular element.

option 1: By class name

driver.findElement(By.className("LstOptSel_sun4"));

option 2: By Xpath.

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='LstOptSel_sun4'")) ;

Also for explicit wait you can use following code

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,100);                 wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By));
driver.findElement(By);

hope this helps your problem.